# Formatting, not printing incorrect format?

Tags: python, variables, format

Hey I'm having an issue getting the last bit of my code to run.
I am unable to get the values at the end and believe it may have to do with my formatting, although I'm not entirely sure. Instead of stabbing in the dark I thought I'd ask around here as the fastest way to improve is with help from the more experienced. 
I'm new, and not seasoned. Haven't been programming for a full 2 months yet.

```
import math
def month():   
    month = input('   # of month born    ')
    if month == '1':
        print ("January")
        return "January"
    elif month == '2':
        print   ("February")
        return "February"
    elif month == '3':
        print  ("March")
        return "March"
    elif month == '4':
        print  ("April")
        return "April"
    elif month == '5':
        print   ("May")
        return "May"
    elif month == '6':
        print("June")
        return ("June")
    elif month == '7':
        print ("July")
        return "July"
    elif month == '8':
        print("August")
        return "August"
    elif month == '9':
        print("september")
        return "September"
    elif month == '10':
        print("October")
        return "October"
    elif month == '11':
        print ("November")
        return "November"
    elif month == '12':
        return "December"
        print ("December")
    else:
        return month()
month()  
print('day born')
day=input(' input day #    ')
print ('{}'.format (day))
if month==1 and day<20:
    print ('Capricorn')
elif month ==1 and day>22:
    print ('aquarius')
```

It does everything fine except return aquarious or capricorn.
How may I format it correctly so it prints these values?

Answer (score 1):

You run the function `month()`, right after the definition of it, but you do not store the return value. You should do this:

```
m = month()
if m == "October":
     # ...
```

But instead, you're comparing the *function* `month` to `1`, which will result to False.

```
def month(): pass    # month is a function
month == 1           # is month equal to 1? no! this is False
```

Also, the function `month` actually returns string by your design, so you should not compare it to `1`, but to `"January"`, for example. Also, there's a very handy builtin package for this, you can use `datetime` here, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior.

```
In [3]: import datetime

In [4]: datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1).strftime('%B')
Out[4]: 'January'

In [5]: datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 1).strftime('%B')
Out[5]: 'December'
```

So in a function:

```
def convert_number_to_month_name(i):
     return datetime.datetime(2000, i, 1).strftime('%B')
```